# How can django produce this SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have the following SQL query that returns what i need:

```
SELECT sensors_sensorreading.*, MAX(sensors_sensorreading.timestamp) AS "last"
FROM sensors_sensorreading
GROUP BY sensors_sensorreading.chipid
```

In words: get the last sensor reading entry for each unique chipid.

But i cannot seem to figure out the correct Django ORM statement to produce this query. The best i could come up with is:

> SensorReading.objects.values('chipid').annotate(last=Max('timestamp'))

But if i inspect the raw sql it generates:

> >>> print connection.queries[-1:]
>
> [{u'time': u'0.475', u'sql': u'SELECT
>   "sensors_sensorreading"."chipid",
>   MAX("sensors_sensorreading"."timestamp") AS "last" FROM
>   "sensors_sensorreading" GROUP BY "sensors_sensorreading"."chipid"'}]

As you can see, it almost generates the correct SQL, except django selects only the chipid field and the aggregate "last" (but i need all the table fields returned instead).

Any idea how to return all fields?

Comment: your SQL query doesn't do what you want it to do... you select the max timestamp (i.e. newest within the group) but the other field values will be from some other row within the group. This is basically why Django ORM doesn't support that query - because it doesn't make sense

Comment: if so - what is the correct way to achieve this? i need the latest reading for each chip....

Comment: the SQL query in JamesZ's answer looks right to me, in which case you need to use raw sql in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also have other fields in the table besides chipid and timestamp, then I would guess this is the SQL you actually need:

```
select * from (
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by chipid order by timestamp desc) as RN
  FROM sensors_sensorreading
) X where RN = 1
```

This will return the latest rows for each chipid with all the data that is in the row.

Comment: WOW! this looks very complex... i have a django alternative, however it is using 2 queries:

 max_set = SensorReading.objects.values('chipid').annotate(last=Max('timestamp'))
query = Q()
for m in max_set:
    query |= (Q(chipid__exact=m['chipid']) & Q(timestamp=m['last']))
data = SensorReading.objects.filter(query)